# Drush error cygintl-2.dll is missing

Tags: drush

So I get the following error "the program can't start because cygintl-2.dll is missing from your computer. try re installing the program to fix this problem" I am getting this error when I try to run a ls command. I have re installed like the pop up suggests. I used the windows installer to install this.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have somehow broken your [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installation. In the Cygwin setup.exe, go through the setup sequence until you get to the "Select Packages" screen, then type "intl" in the Search box. Open the Libs section, and click the third column on the "libintl2" line until it says Reinstall. Proceed.

That should fix this one particular problem, but chances are good that if you've lost that one library, you've broken other things, too. A complete Cygwin reinstallation might be in order.

You too can follow this steps for install drush properly:

[Installing Drush on Windows](https://www.drupal.org/node/594744)

or

[Installing Drush on Windows using Cygwin](https://www.drupal.org/node/1432756)